# error when upgrade to final @angular/cli 1.0.0 : Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse ()

Tags: angular

before upgrade to angular/cli 1.0.0 my service get local json file (for test) working probably with angular-cli 1.0.0 beta 23. Now i got the issue of

> GET http://localhost:4200/json/inputInventory/inputInventory.json 404
>   (Not Found) core.es5.js:1084 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
>   JSON at position 0
>       at Object.parse ()

the current service is :

> .... ommitted
>
> ```
> private inputmaterialInputUrl = 'json/inputInventory/inputMaterial.json';
>
>  constructor(private http: Http) {
> }
>
> getInputPO(): Observable<InputInventoryModel[]> {
>     return this.http.get(this.inputInventoryUrl)
>         .map((res: Response) => res.json())
>         .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Json error"));
>
> } .... omitted
> ```

the component calling service

> .... omitted
>
> export class InputInventoryComponent {
>
> ```
> @ViewChild('largeModal') largeModal;
>
> id: any;
>
> public data: InputInventoryModel[];
> public selectedItem = {
>     id: "0",
>     date: "",
>     PO: "",
>     supplier: "",
>     detail: "",
>     price: "",
>     cost: "",
>     note: ""
> };
>
> constructor(public inventoryService: InventoryService, public router: Router) {
>     inventoryService.getInputPO()
>         .subscribe(items => {
>             this.data = items;
>             console.log(items);
>         });
> } ....omitted
> ```

and the GUI rendering data items via *ngFor expression

the json is formatted and check valid from json online check tool.

json file:

```
[   
{   "id": 1,
    "date": "01/01/2017",
    "PO": "NA12451",
    "supplier": "Công Ty TNHH Việt Nam - TMT 256",
    "detail": ["02 Máy In LINX 1200","02 Keyboard Mítumi","05 Hộp Mực In LINX1200","12 Cartridges 1033"],
    "price": 250000,
    "cost": 21500,
    "note": "This is note 01 for order 01 date 12/12/2016"
```

},
{   "id": 2,
        "date": "01/02/2017",
        "PO": "NA12452",
        "supplier": "Công Ty TNHH Việt Nam - TMT 256",
        "detail": ["05 Hộp Mực In LINX1200","12 Cartridges 1033"],
        "price": 340000,
        "cost": 215000,
        "note": "This is note 01 for order 01 date 12/12/2016"
},
    {"id": 3,
        "date": "01/03/2017",
        "PO": "NB12453",
        "supplier": "Công Ty TNHH Việt Nam - TMT 256",
        "detail": ["02 Máy In LINX 1200","02 Keyboard Mítumi","05 Hộp Mực In LINX1200","12 Cartridges 1033"],
        "price": 250000,
        "cost": 200015,
        "note": "This is note 01 for order 01 date 12/12/2016"
} 
]

I'm not experiencing the issue until i upgrade to angular/cli 1.0.0 and angular 2.4.8

Anybody can help to point out where the issue coming from ? 
I appreciate

Comment: The problem is in the server side, it is not returning JSON, hence you are getting `Unexpected token <` error. Open your chrome debugger and see the result returned.

Comment: No, i did not connect to any back-end yet, just use the json file in the same folder of app , call ing via angular/http service, it worked fine  before upgrade the angular-cli beta 23 to final 1.0.0, rollback to angular-cli beta 23 then everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this error has to do with upgrading Angular CLI, but I'd start with moving the following code to ngOnInit():

```
inventoryService.getInputPO()
    .subscribe(items => {
        this.data = items;
        console.log(items);
    });
```

Comment: i already moved to ngOnInit but it still hapended. rollback to angular-cli beta 23, there is no issue.